# What does the “?” symbol do in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

example

```
SELECT pathName+
               [fileName]+
               fileExtension AS fileName
    FROM BatchCompaniesPaths
 WHERE batchID = ? AND pathType = ?;
```

Comment: It is a placeholder for a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are firing the query from a C# like programming language then `?` must be a parameter holder, you need to pass `sqlparameter` for that place.

For example :

```
OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE id = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = 4;
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

so in the above code the `?` is replaced by @id when the query is fired on database.